# Decide a different 'main' IP for a specific process

Tags: windows, networking, xenapp

I have 3 IP set on my server (Windows Server 2008).

One particular application needs to be working on the 3rd IP, unfortunately the 'bind' paramater of that special application is half working, the application is using my main IP instead to communicate.

The application use "GetHostByName" and/or "GetAddrInfo" to get my main ip. I can know that because I reverse engineered it.

I would like to "spoof"(I think) another main IP for this application. I would like to keep my IP settings as is because everything else is working and I feel I shouldn't touch it.

So basically I would like  "GetHostByName" and "GetAddrInfo" to return another IP of my choice, only to THIS particular application.

I am aware that this probably can't be done exactly as described. Maybe it can, but if not I would like to know what do you guys think the best solution would be to achieve my goal.

Thank you,

Yanick

Answer (score 0):

Well I continued my research, changed my words, finally found this:

https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip

Note: the only thing not working was accessing stuff with 127.0.0.1 (MySQL for example), I had to use my main IP, not sure if my problem, my specific application's problem or a common problem.